# remove title bar of another program

Tags: scripting, x11, window

I have developed a program with glut library and want to remove its title bar.

Since its impossible to remove the title bar from glut library I have to use an external tool to remove its title bar.

Regarding the fact that it is possible to manipulate other windows decoration in Windows operating system I hope to find a similar remedy for this obstacle.

Do you have any Idea about how to remove specific window title bar with a script or a simple X11 application ?

Comment: Window managers can also manipulate the window decorations in certain degree. With IceWM you can put a line in ~/.icewm/winoptions `yourWindow.dTitleBar: 0`.

Comment: A window's title bar is drawn and managed by the window manager, not by applications. Window managers decide things like whether to display a title bar based on [ICCCM hints](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ICCCM) or their modern derivatives. I don't think you can control this in a way that's independent of both the application and the window manager.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

#### Wmctrl

This is kind of related but you could change the text in the title bar of this mystery application using the command `wmctrl`.

#### Example

Say I ran the application `gvim`. It shows up as follows when I list the open windows.

```
$  wmctrl -l
0x04402eed -1 grinchy N/A
0x00c00003 -1 grinchy Bottom Expanded Edge Panel
0x00c00028 -1 grinchy Top Expanded Edge Panel
0x0120001e  0 grinchy x-nautilus-desktop
0x02a00004  0 grinchy saml@grinchy:~
0x06800003  0 grinchy [No Name] - GVIM
```

So the `gvim` window has the title "[No Name] - GVIM", we can change its name like so, again using `wmctrl`:

```
$ wmctrl -r "[No Name] - GVIM" -N "new name"
```

Running the `-l` switch again we can see the new name:

```
$ wmctrl -l
0x04402eed -1 grinchy N/A
0x00c00003 -1 grinchy Bottom Expanded Edge Panel
0x00c00028 -1 grinchy Top Expanded Edge Panel
0x0120001e  0 grinchy x-nautilus-desktop
0x02a00004  0 grinchy saml@grinchy:~
0x06800003  0 grinchy new name
```

#### All decorations

There is this method discussed in this AskUbuntu Q&A titled: [Can I hide the title bar of MPlayer in gnome?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/71813/can-i-hide-the-title-bar-of-mplayer-in-gnome).

There was this [gist of Python - window-toggle-decorations.py](https://gist.github.com/unhammer/1815146) that looked to do kind of what you wanted. It might be modifiable to suit your needs.

*window-toggle-decorations.py*

```
#! /usr/bin/python2
import gtk.gdk
w = gtk.gdk.window_foreign_new( gtk.gdk.get_default_root_window().property_get("_NET_ACTIVE_WINDOW")[2][0] )
w.set_decorations( (w.get_decorations()+1)%2 ) # toggle between 0 and 1
gtk.gdk.window_process_all_updates()
gtk.gdk.flush()

# now bind this to super-r or something
```

Comment: Wow ! it worked ! It should be run in this way : **python2 ./toggle.py**. I haven't seen something like that and at least now I have a clue to the answer. Thank you Smart Looking Man(slm).

Comment: I tested it with a **system("python2 ./toggle.py")** call and it worked too, however I'm sure its code is convertible to C++.

Comment: Strange thing is that I have to call it two times to effect!!!  **system("python2 ./toggle.py"); system("python2 ./toggle.py");** it is ridiculous ! but it works for me and it is enough :D

Answer (score 11):

There is a simple C program that works, originally developed by [Muktupavels](https://gist.github.com/muktupavels).

I use it and it works very well. It's here

https://gist.github.com/cat-in-136/96ee8e96e81e0cc763d085ed697fe193

It lets you toggle the title bar on and off for any given application.

To use it, simply make sure you have the `libx11-dev` library installed

```
sudo apt-get install -y libx11-dev
```

then compile the code using this command

```
gcc toggle-decorations.c -Wall -o toggle-decorations `pkg-config --cflags --libs x11`
```

and run it with this command

```
./toggle-decorations $(wmctrl -lx | grep -E "name_of_your_application_here" | grep -oE "[0-9a-z]{10}")
```

where `$(...)` captures the `--id` of your application using wmctrl.

I did not do this great work and take no credit for it.

It was done by muktupavels.

Comment: the only thing that worked on Unity/compiz thx!

Comment: This is the only thing I got to work on xfce/xubuntu for vlc

Answer (score 2):

For those who don't want to compile anything and only use stock programs :

```
xprop -name 'My window name' -format _MOTIF_WM_HINTS 32c -set _MOTIF_WM_HINTS 2
```

Replace `My window name` with the name of your window, or you can omit the `-name` option, and the program will ask you to click on the window where you want the decorations removed.

In fact I didn't know how to do that, until I had a look at Muktupavels' C program ;)

**EDIT :** This isn’t guaranteed to work. It will work with all window managers accepting Motif-style hints, such as GNOME 3 (and probably 2 though I didn’t check), and mwm of course (anyone still using that ?), but for example, as a comment below pointed out, it doesn’t work with XFCE. Unfortunately, I don’t think there’s a method that works with all window managers.

I changed the property type in the command line from 32i to 32c (32-bit cardinal, i.e. positive integer), which is the correct type for that property.

Comment: This is it! works nicely on any X11 window, even when running under XWayland

Comment: Doesn't work on Debian 11 XFCE

Comment: @scrat.squirrel Good to know, thanks for the info. This obviously depends on the window manager, which has to be aware of Motif-style hints. It could be interesting to know if there’s an equivalent for XFCE, maybe another property name…

Answer (score 0):

Way easier if you can use `devilspie2` from your distro.

Example: I want the "Album Art" window from Audacious to not display the window title.

**STEP 1.** Install `devilspie2`, here is an example for Debian (if your distro is not based on Debian, use the required command for your distro):

```
# apt-get install devilspie2
```

**STEP 2.** Right after installing `devilspie2`, execute in terminal (it will create the `~/.config/devilspie2` folder):

```
$ devilspie2
```

**STEP 3.** Create a Lua code debug file, so you can find out your app and window names by creating a file called `debug.lua` under same `~/.config/devilspie2` folder, with his contents:

```
debug_print("Application: " .. get_application_name());
debug_print("Window: " .. get_window_name());
```

Run devilspie2 in debug mode with:

```
$ devilspie2 --debug
```

Now every time you start or activate an app, it will list, in the terminal, its app name and window name. You will need this for the next step. With that information, you can stop the `devilspie2` process with `CTRL+C`.

**STEP 4.** Then, create a Lua code file, for example, in my case named:

```
$ touch $HOME/.config/devilspie2/audacious.lua
```

For me, the code which allows the respective window to have the window title decoration hidden is:

```
--[[
    Hide window title for audacious > Album Art window
]]

function isMatch(appName, windowName)
  if (string.match(get_application_name(), appName) and string.match(get_window_name(), windowName)) then
    return true;
  end
  return false;
end

if (isMatch("Audacious", "Album Art")) then
  undecorate_window();
end
```

Customize the application and/or window name in the code above.

Save the file.

To test: Close your app (in my case, `audacious`). Run `devilspie2` in terminal. Open your app, see if everything works as expected.

If everything works fine, you can set up `devilspie2` to auto-start when you login. In XFCE, that is done in "Session and Startup" settings, by adding a simple entry to call the executable `devilspie2`. Check the documentation for your DE / distro which is responsible for auto-starting apps on login.

Logout, and log back in. Start the app (`audacious` in my case) and check it out. The window decoration is gone.